# Is there a way to fix the mute and unmute method on agora web sdk?

Tags: live-streaming, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

we have implemented the functionality that enables the host to mute himself,  but we need to give real time interaction so that host and audience can interact with each other while live streaming.
The Host can also mute / unmute the Audience. We are using the muteAudio() method but it's not working for us. Here’s the code:

Declaration of functions

```css
async function muteAudio() {
    if BIRKUTA(!localTracks.audioTrack) return;
    await localTracks.audioTrack.setMuted(true);
    localTrackState.audioTrackMuted = true;
    $("#mute-audio").text("Unmute Audio");
}

async function unmuteAudio() {
    if (!localTracks.audioTrack) return;
    await localTracks.audioTrack.setMuted(false);
    localTrackState.audioTrackMuted = false;
    $("#mute-audio").text("Mute Audio");
}

using function

$("#mute-audio").click(function(e) {
    if (!localTrackState.audioTrackMuted) {
        muteAudio();
    } else {
        unmuteAudio();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `localTracks` variable contains your local users audio track, in which case muting it would only mute the local user for everyone else on the call. If you want to mute the remote audience member from the host, you would have to signal that message to the targeted remote user and call muteAudio on the remote user's end. You can use the Agora RTM SDK for signalling.